# apply style to ul li after a div span that has a specific class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply CSS to the ul li elements following a div section. Using CSS selectors, how to I select the li elements that follow a specific div?  I thought it would be this but it does not work

```
div span.survey_one ~ div ul li{
list-style-type:none;
font-size:1.2rem;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div><span class="survey_one">dddddddddddddd</span>
    <br>
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not see how :first-child helps here.

Comment: The simple answer is, you can't by this tree. As by using `survey_one`, you have to go to the parent and then sibling of that parent....... Unfortunately there is nothing available to get parent from child using only CSS

Comment: Kenny's answer is the correct one.  In my case, i will need to use javascript to accomplish this.  Thanks for the confirmation Kenny.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

The way it is now the general sibling selector is selecting the sibling of `<span class="survey_one">dddddddddddddd</span>`, which is only the `<br>`.

Try setting the general sibling to this instead `div ~ div ul li`

```css
div ~ div ul li{
list-style-type:none;
font-size:1.2rem;
color: red; //added for illustrative purposes
}
```

```html
<div><span class="survey_one">dddddddddddddd</span>
    <br>
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best you place the two div in parent container and select the li like 
.parent li

Or to achieve your initial aim, use javascript to 
1. Select the parent element of the first div using the survey_one class 
2. Transverse to child li of the parent node

Either way, you should place the two divs in a parent container